# Why spring bean profile can not get system property passed from mvn -D?

Tags: spring, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

if I do a `export spring_profiles_default=staging` then run the project it will work. But if I do `mvn -Dspring_profiles_default=staging -pl project/abc jetty:run-exploded`, it will not work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Also I should mention that I put `System.getProperty("spring_profiles_default")` in my code and it does get the value passed from mvn -D so it looks like Spring can not get it for some reason.

Comment: Where do you think should spring resolve/use this property? What do you mean by _will not work_. Please provide more information.

Comment: @Claszen see http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/01/spring-31-cool-new-features.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know about the spring properties `spring.profiles.default`/`spring.profiles.active` ([Spring 3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html)). Did you mix this up with `spring_profiles_default`?

Comment: Yeah, that worked. my ref(http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/01/spring-31-cool-new-features.html) seems to say spring.profiles.default and spring_profiles_default can be used interchangeably, but clearly that is not true.

Comment: You got it to work with `mvn -Dspring.profiles.default=staging`?  I have the same problem you did.  I do not get the profiles recognized when passed via `mvn -D` but exporting `spring_profiles_default` is fine.  Ditto for active.  Annoying.